# How to send Image to Slack as slack bot via slackclient?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm building a simple bot to periodically generate charts as images and post to slack via the python [slackclient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient) package.

I've managed to send a bot message with the code below:

```
def post_message_to_channel(self, channel_id, message=DEFAULT_TEST_MESSAGE):
    sc = SlackClient(TOKEN)
    sc.api_call(
        "chat.postMessage",
        channel=channel_id,
        username='mybot',
        text='test text message'
    )
```

But when I try to do the same with a file upload, the image is sent correctly, but it shows my name, and not the specified bot name:

```
def post_image_to_channel(self, channel_name, filepath, tile='Test Upload'):
    sc = SlackClient(TOKEN)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file_content:
        sc.api_call(
                "files.upload",
                channels=channel_id,
                file=file_content,
                title=tile,
                username='mybot',               
            )
```

Looking at the slack API documentation for [files.upload,](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) it appears that the `username` is not available.

How can I send the *files.upload* image using the bot name?

Comment: @ monkut where did you included the bot message code in your django project is it in views.py

Comment: I used this in a standalone function in aws lambda.  If using django, I'd probably create a `functions.py` in my app directory and put it there.

Comment: Actually I had to sent to a specific user in slack how can I do it

Comment: @ monkut if you dont mind please see this question once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723283/unable-to-send-messages-to-slack-from-my-django-app-using-python-slackclient?noredirect=1#comment109188235_61723283 its my friends please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send the file using a Bot User Token of a bot-user. You can find more info at the official documentation https://api.slack.com/bot-users

Comment: Yes, I had to 'install app' and then create a bot user.  It was sort of hard to find the links/path to actually get the bot token.  With the bot token, the username defined on bot creation is properly applied.

Comment: Any idea how to set the bot image?

Comment: The bot user will use the image of your Slack app, which you can update in your Slack App Management page under "Basic Information"

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to send your images as part of a [message attachments](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments). That way you can also include some context information around the chart. And since you are sending a message you have still full control over username etc.

Comment: does image_url in attachments works for system image file too ? where we can use path of file

Comment: @Eyshika The URL has to be a image file hosted on an Internet server. It does not work with a local file path. Just upload your images to a image server like imgur and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import slack
import json
import os

def pureimg(data1):
        data1 = '[{"text": "", "image_url": "'+data1+'"}]'
        data1 = [json.loads(data1[1:-1])]
        return data1

#This function will make the image url to correct format.

slacker = slack.WebClient(token='your-token-here')

payoff=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'filename.png')
#It gives cross OS compatibility on filepath.

response=slacker.files_upload(channel='#theta',file=payoff)
payoff=response['file']['permalink']

#First We upload the local file to Slack and fetch permalink.
#If you do not have any local file just put the external image URL in the payoff.

response=slacker.chat_postMessage(channel='#channel_name', text="Sample Text", username='Bot name', attachments=pureimg(payoff), icon_emoji=':emoji:')

#Then, We post to Slack Channel as a bot!
```

Comment: I couldnt get this to work. Looks like the file is not uploaded to the channel